# Filtering my react state (array of objects)

Tags: arrays, object, filter, onchange, react-state

I have an event handler that is meant to filter a chosen item out of a  stateful array. Currently it is filtering everything out of the array instead of the intended selection.

[image]

So when I click the remove button of one card both/all cards are removed even though they have different ids...

Lastly, how can I filter the menu cards based on the `searchbar` input?

This is what my components looks like

top level

```
import Favorites from "./Favorites";
import { Menu } from "./Menu";
import { useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState([]);
  const [array, setArray] = useState([
    {
      text: "Check 123",
      name: "Lahmacun",
      image: "src/lahmacun.jpeg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 456",
      name: "Chicken",
      image: "src/chicken.webp",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 789",
      name: "Veggies",
      image: "src/vegan.jpeg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
    {
      text: "Check 012",
      name: "Pho",
      image: "src/pho.jpeg",
      id: self.crypto.randomUUID(),
      liked: false,
    },
  ]);

  const handleLike = (card) => {
    setFavorite((prev) => [...prev, card]);
  };

  const handleUnlike = (id) => {
    console.log("removed");
    setFavorite(favorite.filter((item) => item.id == id));
  };

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Recipes To Try</h1>
      <form className="m-2" action="">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-3 ">
            <label className="form-label pt-2" id="searchBar">
              Find A Recipe
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-7 col-5">
            <input
              //onChange={filterRecipes}
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="searchBar"
              placeholder="Search"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-1 col-2">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" id="searchBtn">
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <Favorites favorite={favorite} handleUnlike={handleUnlike} />
      <Menu array={array} handleLike={handleLike} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

favorite component

```
export default function Favorites({ favorite, handleUnlike }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="holder">
        <h3>Favorites</h3>
        <div id="favorites">
          {favorite.map((i) => (
            <div
              className="col col-md mb-3 mb-sm-0"
              key={self.crypto.randomUUID()}
            >
              <div className="card">
                <img src={i.image} alt="" className="card-img-top " />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h5 className="card-title">{i.name}</h5>
                  <p className="card-text">{i.text}</p>
                  <a
                    onClick={() => handleUnlike(i)}
                    href="#"
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                  >
                    Remove
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Menu component

```
import { Cards } from "./Cards";

export function Menu({ array, handleLike }) {
  return (
    <div id="menu">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <h3 className="">Ready for Testing</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <Cards array={array} handleLike={handleLike} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Card Component

```
export function Cards({ array, handleLike }) {
  return (
    <>
      {array.map((i) => (
        <div className="col col-md mb-3 mb-sm-0" key={i.id}>
          <div className="card">
            <img src={i.image} alt="" className="card-img-top " />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{i.name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{i.text}</p>
              <a
                onClick={() => handleLike(i)}
                href="#"
                className="btn btn-primary"
              >
                Add to Favorites
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Thanks a bunch

I expect just one item to be filtered but both were

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is your i passed in handleUnlike is not the id but the object.

```
<a onClick={() => handleUnlike(i)}
                href="#"
                className="btn btn-primary"
              >
```

change it to this and it will work

```
  <a onClick={() => handleUnlike(i.id)}
            href="#"
            className="btn btn-primary"
          >
```

the origin of your problem is inproper naming of your objects
if you give everything a meaningful name, you will spot these errors easier.

instead of

```
{favorite.map((i) => (...))}
```

do

```
{favoriteRecipes.map((recipe) => (...))}
```

for filtering, instead of showing the original list, you create a second list.

because you are using a button for searching you will need to add a useRef for the textfield. (this will prevent unnecessary rerendering)

```
const [filteredRecipes, setFilteredRecipes] = useState(array);
const searchTextRef = useRef();
```

then in the onClick handler of the searchButton, you do the filtering.

```
const onSearchRecipe = () => setFilteredRecipes(array.filter(recipe => recipe.name.includes(searchTextRef.current.value) !== -1));
```

change the part of your inputfield and button to the following

```
<div className="col-md-7 col-5">
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={searchTextRef}
          className="form-control"
          id="searchBar"
          placeholder="Search"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-1 col-2">
        <button 
          onClick={onSearchRecipe} type="button" className="btn btn-primary" id="searchBtn">
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
```

and then last pass in your filtered list to the menu instead of the array

```
 <Menu array={filteredRecipes} handleLike={handleLike} />
```

Comment: Thanks Mathieu! I will try to use more meaningful names to avoid this in the future. good tip! Any idea about the second question relating to filtering the menu items? I want to give you the check for a correct answer.

Comment: no problem @shimmyshimmyya7347, i changed the answer to add the filtering.
I did not test it because I am in a hurry, but you will understand the direction. 
if you want to filter when typing this link will explain it: to you https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/filter-list-as-you-type-with-react/
Good luck